# RFC 4474 and special case of REGISTER methods

Tags: voip, sip

I was going thru RFC 4474 and noticed that it has some trouble in dealing with authentication in REGISTER and CANCEL message.
Has anyone went thru RFC 4474 and noticed why REGISTER and CANCEL message cannot be authenticated by the method suggested by RFC 4474?

RFC 4474 says,  pp. 16.

> Note, in the table above, that this mechanism does not protect the
>   CANCEL method. The CANCEL method cannot be challenged, because it is
>   hop-by-hop, and accordingly authentication service behavior for CANCEL
>   would be significantly limited. Note as well that the REGISTER method
>   uses Contact header fields in very unusual ways that complicate its
>   applicability to this mechanism, and the use of Identity with REGISTER
>   is consequently a subject for future study, although it is left as
>   optional here for forward-compatibility reasons. The Identity and
>   Identity-Info header MUST NOT appear in CANCEL.

CANCEL message unauthenticated can only be a threat for a certain duration after the REGISTER message has been sent and before ACK arrives. So it might be less of a threat.
but REGISTER message unauthenticated can cause potential problem, as RFC states that REGISTER uses contact headers in unusual ways, as far as i know, it just has the FROM and TO headers same. But why is this causing problem in implementing this technique to it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the RFC correctly. There's no message called REQUEST. I am guessing that you are referring to the INVITE transaction. To make a long answer short, the CANCEL is more or less a copy of the INVITE transaction it is cancelling. When doing MD5 challenge/response authentication we use two different transactions, and thus if we authenticated the CANCEL it would no longer be a copy of the INVITE because you had another CSEQ.

I recommend you read through the basics in RFC 3261 to understand more of this.

/O